# Using apache commons email library getting error must issue a starttls command first. Please help

Tags: java, apache-commons-email

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
String authuser = "......@gmail.com";
String authpwd = "*******";
// Very Important, Don't use email.setAuthentication()
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(authuser, authpwd));
email.setDebug(true); // true if you want to debug
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");

email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.debug", "true");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
email.setFrom("........@gmail.com", "SenderName");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail?");
email.addTo(".............@gmail.com", "ToName");
email.setTLS(true);
email.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all `email.getMailSession().getProperties()` - they are not required and may be polluting the setup.

Then remove the line that sets the port. (`email.setSmtpPort(587);`)

Comment: I removed all those email.getMailSession().getProperties() but still getting the error STARTTLS command. Also did setSSL(true) then getting the error class javax.mail.MessagingException:Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Cannot find the specified class java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory